# How do I create a SpatialLinesDataFrame from a dataframe?

Tags: r, line

I have created a data.frame in R . I want to get SpatialLinesDataFrame as a result so I understand that I have to convert the data.frame into lines, the lines into SpatialLines and the SpatialLines into SpatialLinesDataFrame. I did this

```
filedata.frame=data.frame(matrix(file),ncol=14, byrow=T))
file=Lines(filedata.frame)
```

I get the data.frame I want but not the lines. I am sure is basic but why I can't get the lines?

Comment: How does your dataframe look like? How are the coordinates stored? Did you check `?Lines`? Lines need two parameters as input `Lines(slinelist, ID)`

Comment: So every line has beginning point and final point. You are right about the Lines, I did it :for (i in seq_along(lines)) {
  lines[[i]] <- Lines(list(Line(rbind(c(file$x_f[i],file$y_f[i]),  c(filedf$x_tr[i], filedf$y_tr[i]) ))), as.character(i))
}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an extended example from the [**sp** vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/intro_sp.pdf) that demonstrates how to create a 'SpatialLinesDataFrame' from an ordinary 'data.frame' object. I use some sample data created from the lengths of the single 'SpatialLines' via `gLength` from **rgeos**. Note that the `rownames` of the created dataset passed on to `SpatialLinesDataFrame` must be identical to the previously defined line IDs (in this particular case "a" and "b").

```
library(sp)

## from the sp vignette:
l1 <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 2))
l2 <- cbind(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 1.5, 1))

Sl1 <- Line(l1)
Sl2 <- Line(l2)

S1 <- Lines(list(Sl1), ID = "a")
S2 <- Lines(list(Sl2), ID = "b")

Sl <- SpatialLines(list(S1, S2))

## sample data: line lengths
library(rgeos)
df <- data.frame(len = sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) gLength(Sl[i, ])))
rownames(df) <- sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) Sl@lines[[i]]@ID)


## SpatialLines to SpatialLinesDataFrame
Sldf <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(Sl, data = df)

plot(Sldf, col = c("red", "blue"))
text(labels = paste0("length = ", round(Sldf@data$len, 2)), 
     x = gCentroid(Sldf, byid = TRUE)$x,
     y = gCentroid(Sldf, byid = TRUE)$y)
```

[image]